# Weird characters in an old document I'm trying to recover

Tags: microsoft-word

Here is a sample of the text that is in a Word file that is now labeled a `.txt` document. If I delete the extra space in parts that actually contain my old text, about half the text is missing when I reopen the document in Word. I assume that my data is still there, but it somehow changed to this weird stuff.

```
ÐÏà¡±á                >  þÿ                               
þÿÿÿ          
ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿýÿÿÿþÿÿÿþÿÿÿ
ýÿÿÿ                                                     
                               !   "   #   $   %   &   '   ( 
)   *   +   ,   -   .   /   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   : 
;   <   =   >   ?   @   A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L 
M   N   O   P   Q   R   S   T   U   V   W   X   Y   Z   [   \   ]   ^ 
_   `   a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t   u   v   w   x   y   z   {   |   }   ~      €   R o o
t   E n t r y                                              
ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ   ²Z¤ žÑ¤ ÀO¹2º            ðàš-Á¤Ìñ          C O N T E
N T S                                                        ÿÿÿÿ

    Ú      C o m p O b j                                                   ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ                                        V       S P E
L L I N G                                                  
ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ                                       h         þÿÿÿ 

                   þÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿi
e f   t h a t   T i n k e r b e l l   d i d n ' t   g o   t o   a   f
a r m .     U n l e s s   w e ' r e   t a l k i n g   a b o u t   t h
e   b i g   f a r m   i n   t h e   s k y .     B u t   e v e n   w i
t h   t h e   l o s s   o f   T i n k e r ,     w e   s t i l l   h a
d   a   l o t   t o   b e   h a p p y   a b o u t ,   b e c a u s e  
t h a t   w a s   a b o u t   t h e   s a m e   t i m e   w e   w e n
t   t o   p i c k   u p   A n n i e   a t   t h e   h o s p i t a l . 
S o m e   o t h    ‚   ƒ   „   …   †   ‡   ˆ   ‰   Š   ‹   Œ      Ž 
      ‘   ’   “   ”   •   –   —   ˜   ™   š   ›   œ      ž   Ÿ     
¡   ¢   £   ¤   ¥   ¦   §   ¨   ©   ª   «   ¬   ­   ®   ¯   °   ±   ² 
³   ´   µ   ¶   ·   ¸   ¹   º   »   ¼   ½   ¾   ¿   À   Á   Â   Ã   Ä 
Å   Æ   Ç   È   É   Ê   Ë   Ì   Í   Î   Ï   Ð   Ñ   Ò   Ó   Ô   Õ   Ö 
×   Ø   Ù   Ú   Û   Ü   Ý   Þ   ß   à   á   â   ã   ä   å   æ   ç   è 
é   ê   ë   ì   í   î   ï   ð   þÿÿÿò  
þÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿe r   m o m m
a   c o u l d n  t   t a k e   c a r e   o f   h e r ,   a n d   s o 
s h e   w a s   g i v i n g   A n n i e   t o   u s .     W e   h a d 
a   n e w   l i t t l e   b a b y   s i s t e r .     I t   w a s   t
h e   c o o l e s t   t h i n g   t o   h o l d   h e r .     S h e  
w a s   s o   s m a l l .     W e   h a d   t o   b e   v e r y   g e
n t l e   a n d   m a k e   s u r e   t o   s u p p o r t   h e r   n
e c k .     I   c o u l d   s i t   f o r   a   l o n g   t i m e   a
n d   j u s t   h o l d   h e r . . .     i t   w a s   s o   c o o l
.        S h o r t l y   a f t e r   t h a t ,   w e   h a d   m o v e d 
t o   P o r t l a n d ,   t o   s t a r t   a   n e w   l i f e .    
D a d   w a s   g o i n g   t o   g o   t o   s c h o o l   a t   P o
r t l a n d   S t a t e   U n i v e r s i t y   a n d   w o r k   a t 
F r e d   M e y e r  s .     S o   I   g u e s s   w h e n   D a d  
b r o u g h t   h o m e   t h a t   p u p p y   a n d   i t   l o o k
e d   s o   m u c h   l i k e   T i n k e r
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the extension back to .DOC (or .DOCX) to see if Word will then open it?

Comment: Sometime, if this is all you have to work with, it is faster to look at the mess and retype it into a new document than to try to clean it up.

Comment: This 'text file' looks like something you might have recovered using file recovery software. I'd recommend using [TrID](http://mark0.net/soft-tridnet-e.html) to automatically add the correct file extension to the files you're not sure are right. It works like the `file` command on Linux machines.

Answer (score 1):

That “weird” stuff is most likely the stuff that Microsoft Word puts in the file when it creates a standard `.doc` document. This [discussion here](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=39&p=11496149) touches on that:

> That looks like trash produced by Word when you try to attach it to a message.

Simply changing the extension to `.doc` and loading it through Microsoft Word should clear it up. And it most likely was named `.txt` at some point in the past on a system that somehow associated that file with Microsoft Word. If the association is lost, the system would assume it is a `.txt` file and just load it as such… Which is clearly not the case.